# Understanding Concurrent.unicast's arguments

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework-2.2, loops

I use Play Framework 2.2

In order to implement a WebSocket connection, I use a `Concurrent.unicast` that fits my needs:

```
val enumerator = Concurrent.unicast[JsValue] {
    channel => userIdWithChannelMap += u.id -> channel
}
```

However, the [source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Concurrent.scala) of `Concurrent.unicast` shows the needs of several arguments:

```
def unicast[E](
    onStart: Channel[E] => Unit,
    onComplete: => Unit = (),
    onError: (String, Input[E]) => Unit = (_: String, _: Input[E]) => ())(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
```

I understand that `onComplete` is executed when an `Iteratee` is `Done`.
However what is the difference between `onComplete` callback and the `map` method of the `Iteratee`:

```
/**
   *
   * Uses the provided function to transform the Iteratee's computed result when the Iteratee is done.
   *
   * @param f a function for transforming the computed result
   * $paramEcSingle
   */
  def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Iteratee[E, B] = this.flatMap(a => Done(f(a), Input.Empty))(ec)
```

Besides, what is the need for `Enumerator#onDoneEnumerating`, presented in the [source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Enumerator.scala).
Indeed, I came across some implementation of WebSocket dealing with:

```
Concurrent.unicast{...}.onDoneEnumerating{...}
```

I'm confused with `onComplete`, `onDoneEnumerating` and `Iteratee#map`.
May anyone explain the differences?
And especially, why `Concurrent#broadcast` doesn't present an `onComplete` argument as `unicast` does.

Hard to find some good docs about the `Iteratee` world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of these is different, but the differences are subtle.

The `onComplete` parameter of `unicast` lets you setup a callback for when the Iteratee that it is applied to completes successfully. The separate `onError` callback is for when it fails.

The `onDoneEnumerating` method of `Enumerator` lets you attach a callback that will be called if the `Iteratee` either completes successfully or fails.

`Iteratee.map` allows you to attach a callback to an `Iteratee` that completes successfully, and alter the value that it completes with.

`Concurrent.broadcast` doesn't take `onComplete` or `onError` callbacks because it can be applied to multiple `Iteratee` instances, which won't necessarily behave the same way. One instance may die with an error, while another one completes successfully at a later time, while another never completes. Because of this it is unlikely for it to make sense for the code running the Enumerator to react to these events.